# How do i get a poll result from a friends poll in facebook using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to retrieve a results data using php in facebook, but the question was made by a friend not me, the link is http://www.facebook.com/questions/108352712644317/

is it possible?
i read the documentations but no luck, didnt find anythins like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app needs to grant the friends_questions permission to read your friends questions and then read the questionsOptions table for the answers

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question_option/

I believe you can only get your own questions, and friends questions. Though doing something like https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/questions seems to work as well for public pages like Coca Cola etc.

Comment: So this friend need to autorize an app made by me then i can read this question right? theres no other way?

Comment: If it's your app you can authorize the friends_questions permission on your account to read your friends questions. Your friend doesn't need to do it. However if they aren't actually your friend and you're just trying to access and random question you don't know the id to, then I don't think it will work

Comment: yes, if you look at the links I posted it shows the permissions you need. In fact, just polling the question should give you the options and votes as well. Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/questions and you can explore the format of your questions and the response